# How I can check my iOS app is working with proxy checks or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have one app which is not working in some school networks but working in our company network.

So there is some proxy checks they have in there school network.

My problem is I want to check before giving app to school to test whether it is working or not with proxy checks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask the school authorities to setup the HTTP proxy on their iDevices. Or just see if you are using some web APIs that they have blocked in their proxy. Our school had Youtube and Facebook blocked so you could not communicate with Facebook APIs